# Drawing eyes on planets & bodies but no face

Tags: animals, drawing

Hi I’m an **artist** who draws bodies with clothes on them like on catwalks but I draw **no** eyes, nose, mouth or ears. Is that allowed? And I also drew planets like Jupiter  **with** eyes on them but **no** mouth or whatsoever. Is this allowed? And are you allowed to draw skeletons of animals? Sorry for the amount of questions but I’m really  at my turning point because I really am trying to do good deeds and pray but when I’m done with homework I have free time and I like to draw. Please educate me on this. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know so much details, I know that drawing living things is not a good thing, so I will give my advice depending on what I see.

My advice is: Draw creatively planets and unliving things(Trees, Rocks, etc.) and do not draw eyes, mouth, nose, etc. And avoid drawing living things(Cats, Humans, etc.) completely.

I think that is fun enough with being on the safe side.

Comment: Thank you! But what if you draw like a mouth on paper but nothing else?

Comment: You can See this : https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/260883/%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%89%D9%84%D8%A9-%D9%85%D8%AA%D9%86%D9%88%D8%B9%D8%A9-%D8%AD%D9%88%D9%84-%D9%85%D8%A7-%D9%8A%D8%AC%D9%88%D8%B2-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%B1%D8%B3%D9%85-%D8%B0%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AD-%D9%88%D9%85%D8%A7-%D9%84%D8%A7-%D9%8A%D8%AC%D9%88%D8%B2

if you cant read arabic , I think you can translate . Please read it all so you can understand.

Comment: In anyways it is also said in the website that **The advice is to let a person from drawing animate beings altogether, even if the features are obscured, and to limit himself to drawing inanimate plants and inanimate objects, for this is the safest and most cautious.** It is my advice also, be aware because it is dangerous from the promise that Allah gave to the people who draw living things. Becareful please! Thank you